# How to remove apparent redundency in numpy vector operations?

Tags: arrays, numpy, vectorization

New to python and not sure about efficiency issues here.  For vectors x, y, and z that represent the coordinates of n particles I can do the following computation

```
import numpy as np
X=np.subtract.outer(x,x)
Y=np.subtract.outer(y,y)
Z=np.subtract.outer(z,z)
R=np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2+Z**2)
A=X/R
np.fill_diagonal(A,0)
a=np.sum(A,axis=0)
```

With this calculation there is about a factor of 2 in redundancy in so far as multiplications and divisions go as the diagonals are not needed and the lower diagonal is just the negative of the upper diagonal.  I plan to use this kind of computation inside a function call that is used by odeint - i.e. it would be called a lot and the vectors will be large - as large as my computer will handle.  To remove it, naively I would end up doing a for loop which presumably is a stupid thing to do.  Can I get rid of this redundancy in a vectorized way or is it even worth the effort?

Update:  Based on the suggestions below, the only way I could see to improve was

```
ut=np.triu_indices(n,1)
X=x[ut[0]]-x[ut[1]]
```

With similar expressions for Y and Z and using pdist to find R.  This construction only calculates the upper triangular part.  Looking at the source code for pdist I am not convinced it does anything particularly smart so I think my expression above would be equally good.  The use of squareform only produces the symmetric form.  For the antisymmetric may as well use

```
B=np.zeros((n,n),dtype=np.float64)
B(ut[0],ut[1])=A
B=B-B.T
```

This cannot be slower than square form because this is pretty much exactly what squareform does.  Since the function is called often it would seem to me that ut should be made static along with storage for others (X,Y,Z,A,B).  However being new to python I'm not sure how that is done.

Comment: Have a look at `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` to efficiently calculate the pairwise distance and `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform` to turn the "condensed" result back into a 2D array.

Comment: @Joe I think that is almost what I need.  But looking at the pdist function it seems it only works for symmetric distance function and I would need an anti-symmetric function but maybe I can fudge that at the end.

Comment: Yes, that's basically why I didn't post a full answer.  I posted the comment before I realized that.  By the time you make it work for an anti-symmetric distance array, it's a very modest speed-up (~20%).  However, if you needed `abs(x - x) / r` instead of the "raw" difference, you could get a much larger speedup.

Comment: Doesn't `np.nansum(X/sp.spatial.distance.squareform(sp.spatial.distance.pdist(xyz)),0)
` work, where `xyz` is the concatenated array?

Comment: @Divakar - Yes, but it's not significantly faster than the op's current approach (my "~20%" number is based on more or less that approach).

Comment: @JoeKington I see, I didn't time those, good to see those numbers!

Comment: You could even do `a=np.sum(A,0)-np.diagonal(A)`, though the timings are same as for the `fill_diagonal` approach.

Comment: Thanks all for your input.  @Divakar squareform doesn't do the antisymmetric form.  See my update for the fix.  Have to confess I wasn't sure how to time things to properly to test.  I saw %timeit used elsewhere but that generated an error for me.

Comment: `%timeit` is a "magic" command that only works in the IPython console, not a regular python session.